# How to set full-page pdf using mpdf library?

Tags: php, pdf, package, laravel-8, mpdf

I am generating pdf from dynamic data using mpdf library in laravel 8. It has page break, But I want to show in single page.

[image]

---

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('vcard.card-pdf', compact('card_details', 'plan_details', 'business_card_details', 'feature_details', 'service_details', 'galleries_details', 'payment_details', 'business_hours', 'settings', 'shareComponent', 'shareContent', 'config', 'enquiry_button'),[], [
                                'format'           => 'A4', 
                                'display_mode'     => 'fullpage'
                    ]);
```

Comment: Could this not be a viewer software issue?

Comment: @KJ not working. same result

Comment: @KJ no it is different